# Move one column in the row to the third row after (for the whole database) sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have big database with few columns ex. `ID`, `SomeID`, `t1`, `aa`, `bb`, `cc`.

What I want to achieve is for all rows to move the column `SomeID` three rows lower.

Example :

```
  ID    SomeID, t1, aa..
  1   , Text1,   some,some...
  2   , Text2,   some,some...
  3   , Text3,   some,some...
  4   , Text4,   some,some...
```

and after the SQL command the `text1` go be in column `SomeID` with ID 3, and text2 to be in column SomeID with ID 4

Can anyone refer where can I find such a command?

Comment: so what will be present in `someid` when `ID=1`

Comment: this is a calendar in which in 1 ( for the example 1 of jan 2015 will take the data form 29 of dec 2014)- and i will only update rows for 2015

Comment: Still am not clear can edit the question with expected result.

Comment: Are ID-s in numerical order?

Comment: Are you looking for a `SELECT` or an `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can do self join.

```
  SELECT t1.id, t2.SomeID, t2.any_other_col
  FROM tab t1, tab t2
  where t1.id + 2= t2.id
```

From question it is not clear if ID is in numerical order to match. You can apply similar logic on date as well.

Comment: Self join will fail if id there are deleted/missing id

Comment: I would use RowNunber() function to label each row, insert it into a temp table then perform self join based on the rownumber column, shifted by 2 ofcourse.